# How to extract attributes from array using XmlSerializer?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, deserialization, xmlserializer, xml-deserialization

I want to extract the image attribute "href" using XmlSerializer.

It will work if my setup looks like this :

```
<images>
       <image id="285">  
          http://images1.com/test.jpg" 
       </image>

       <image id="286">
          http://images1.com/test.jpg"
       </image>       
</images>
```

---

But not if it looks like this:

```
<images>
    <image href=http://images1.com/test.jpg" id="285" />
    <image href=http://images1.com/test.jpg" id="286" />        
</images>
```

---

Here is my  object

```
   private string[] imageList;
   [XmlArrayItem("image", typeof(object))]
   [XmlArray("images")]

    public string[] imageLink
    {
        get
        {
            return imageList;
        }
        set
        {
            imageList = value;
        }

    }
```

---

Comment: Have you considered using Linq to Xml for this rather than a serializer?

Comment: @JamieSee Yes I have , I am using XBOX XDK, I don't believe there is support for Linq on XBOX.

Comment: @JamieSee , Found out that this can be accomplished with XDocument as well.

Comment: Yes it can, and it's actually easier with XDcoument. I didn't suggest that because it's part of System.Xml.Linq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried multiple ways to try to get a serializer to conform to this XML without much luck.

You may just want to do something like this:

```
    string xml = @"<images>
    <image href=""http://images1.com/test.jpg"" id=""285"" />
    <image href=""http://images1.com/test2.jpg"" id=""286"" />        
</images>";

    List<string> images = new List<string>();
    using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml))
    using (XmlTextReader xr = new XmlTextReader(sr))
    {
        while (!xr.EOF)
        {
            xr.MoveToContent();
            xr.ReadToDescendant("image");
            xr.MoveToAttribute("href");
            xr.ReadAttributeValue();            
            images.Add(xr.Value);
            xr.MoveToElement();
            if (xr.Name != "images")
            {
                xr.ReadElementString();
            }
            else
            {
                xr.ReadEndElement();
            }
        }
    }
```

I've done some more poking at it and came up with a way to use serialization and get the desired XML:

```
[XmlRoot("images")]
public class ImageListWrapper
{
    public ImageListWrapper()
    {
        Images = new List<Image>(); 
    }

    [XmlElement("image")]
    public List<Image> Images
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public List<string> GetImageLocations()
    {
        List<string> imageLocations = new List<string>();

        foreach (Image image in Images)
        {
            imageLocations.Add(image.Href);
        }

        return imageLocations;
    }
}

[XmlRoot("image")]
public class Image
{
    [XmlAttribute("href")]
    public string Href { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yeah its seems I either have to refactor my XML or use this this nifty  piece of code you provided. Thanks very much, in the meanwhile I'm going to see if anyone can come with an XML serializer solution.

Comment: I did some more work with it this morning and found a way that works with serialization with your exact XML.

Comment: I came up with the same breakdown, but missed a couple steps. Thanks man , you are a life saver.

Comment: When I deserialize am I deserializing to type : ImageListWrapper ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. `ImageListWrapper.Images` contains the list of images. You can get the href content from there, i.e. `imageListWrapper.Images[0].Href`. It should be fairly simple to add a `public List<string> GetImageLocations()` to the ImageWrapper class if you like.